# O que são esses atributos nas propriedades?

Tags: c#, .net, sintaxe, atributos

Qual o nome desses "Atributos" e para que são utilizados?

Exemplos:

na declaração de uma classe:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class SerializableAttribute : Attribute
```

na declaração de uma propriedade:

```
[XmlElement]
public string Valor
{
   get { return _valor; }
   set { _valor = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você já viu nas outras respostas o que é um atributo.

Eles podem ser usados em:

- Assembly,
- Module,
- Class,
- Struct,
- Enum,
- Constructor,
- Method,
- Property,
- Field,
- Event,
- Interface,
- Parameter,
- Delegate,

Um exemplo de uso em parâmetros.

```
void metodo([nonnull] string texto)
```

Usando em *assembly*:

```
[assembly: Help("this a do-nothing assembly")]
```

Como nota-se é possível identificar explicitamente onde o atributo será usado. Em alguns casos é a única forma de determinar o escopo correto. Veja os identificadores possíveis:

- assembly
- module
- type
- method
- property
- event
- field
- param
- return

Eles são usados para adicionar metadados a o código. Algo que o compilador já faz em diversas oportunidades de acordo com o uso da linguagem. Este recurso permite que o usuário da linguagem (o programador) possa adicionar seus próprios atributos. Você pode usar atributos criados por terceiros, inclusive pelo próprio .Net e outras bibliotecas da Microsoft ou não, ou usar atributos que você criou.

Alguns destes atributos são usados através de [reflexão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) por bibliotecas e mais comumente por *frameworks*. Pode ser usado pelo compilador para mudar seu comportamento em relação a alguma coisa. Ou pode ser usado por ferramentas externas como IDEs se aproveitarem disto, especialmente em geradores de código, os que ajudam interoperabilidade.

Há muita utilização errada destes atributos inclusive pela própria Microsoft em alguns pontos. ["Escute" o mestre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297880/221800).

## Sintaxe diferente

Veja este exemplo

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

Ele determina que um membro poderá ser acessado diretamente por um objeto [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model).

Mas não é tão comum escrever assim, O mais comum é assim:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```

Mas como? Eu fui lá na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) e vi que o nome dele é `ComVisibleAttribute`. O compilador usa um truque aí.

Para definir um novo atributo você deve criar uma classe derivada de `Attribute` e por convenção o nome deve terminar com a palavra `Attribute` para evitar conflitos. Mas para usar de forma mais simples o compilador quando você **usa** o atributo em algum local do código o compilador procura por ele com o nome usado ou com o sufixo `Attribute`.

A própria classe que cria um atributo pode ter atributos específicos. É comum o uso de `AttributeUSage`, `ValidOn`, `AllowMultiple`, `Inherited`

## Outros exemplos:

```
[XmlElement]
```

É utilizado para indicar ao `XMLSerializer` que aquele membro é um membro a ser considerado como XML. Então é um atributo criado pelo .Net para auxiliar uma de suas classes.

```
[Browsable(false)]
```

Determina se o membro será visível ou não na janela Properties do IDE.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{value}", Name = "{key}")]
```

Como deve mostrar aquele membro quando estiver inspecionando valores no *debugger*.

```
[Flags]
```

Torna uma enumeração um *bitfield*, ou seja, cada membro terá o valor evoluindo geometricamente à razão de 2 para depois ser usado com operador `|` e "somar" elementos.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

Determina em qual tipo de *release* aquele código deve ser executado.

```
[Serializable]
```

Determina que o membro pode ser serializado. Comummente usado em conjunto com `[NonSerializable]`.

```
[Optional]
```

Usado primariamente pelo compilador para indicar o valor que um parâmetro deve assumir se ele não for passado. Assim pode ser usado até por linguagens que não tenha este conceito. Usado em conjunto com `[DefaultParameterValue("texto")]`.

```
[Test]
```

Indica que o método é um teste de unidade. Ferramentas deste precisam saber o que executar.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ClasseX")]
```

Faz o mesmo que o atributo `Friend` do C++.

[Lista completa criada no .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#inheritanceContinued).

Um [exemplo do que não fazer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_attributes.htm) (veja no final da página. Esta informação adicionada não deveria fazer parte do código e principalmente star disponível no executável.

## Parâmetros para atributos

Não é possível usar qualquer informação como parâmetro de um atributo (que são membros da classe que define o atributo). Precisa ser um tipo que pode ser resolvido em tempo de compilação. Pode usar:

- bool,
- byte,
- char,
- double,
- float,
- int,
- long,
- short,
- string
- System.Type
- object
- enum (com restrições)
- array (com restrições)

Exemplo de uso:

```
using System;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class HelpAttribute : System.Attribute {
   public readonly string text;

   public HelpAttribute(string text) {
      this.text = url;
   }
}
[HelpAttribute("http://site/MyClassInfo")]
class MyClass {
    [Help("Método inútil")]
    public void MyMethod() {}

    [Help("Meu inteiro")]
    public int MyInt;
}
class App {
    public static void Main() {
        var assembly = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
        foreach (Attribute attr in Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly).GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
            var help = attr as HelpAttribute;
            if (help != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Descrição de {0}:\n{1}", assembly, help.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetCustomAttribute%2Ccs).

Answer (score 7):

Este é o nome correto. **Atributos**, ou então no inglês, *Attributes*.

Atributos tem várias funções:

- Definir informações sobre a classe, propriedade ou método, que serão usadas em tempo de execução;
- Adicionar comportamentos funcionais à classe, propriedade ou método;
- Definir agrupamentos ou segregações.

[Aqui há uma introdução a Attributes (em inglês)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664611(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
[Obsolete("Não utilizar esse método.")]
public void Metodo();

[Serializable]
public class Classe();

[WebMethod]
public static void Listar();
```

Esses nomes entre chaves acima de cada nome de método ou declaração de classe são os **atributos** e servem para identificar e classificar classes e seus campos segundo alguns critérios, atribuindo-lhes propriedades específicas para utilização no contexto em que são utilizadas.

Por exemplo, o atributo `Obsolete` permite definir uma mensagem indicando que o método está obsoleto e indicando qual utilizar em seu lugar.

Fonte: [Trabalhando com atributos de classe e Reflection em C#](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-atributos-de-classe-e-reflection-em-c/26893#ixzz3MiWzFW2m), nesse artigo o autor ensinar a criar seu próprio atributo customizado, recomendo a leitura.