# O que são metadados no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, terminologia, reflexão

O que são metadados em C#/.NET? Pra que servem, e como posso utilizá-los?

Estava observando uma *template* do Visual Studio, e navegando pelos arquivos, me deparei com eles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dentro da [Common Language Infrastructure](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) usada pelo .NET está previsto o uso destes metadados para dar mais informações sobre o funcionamento das aplicações. Estas informações podem ser as mais variadas e podem ser inseridos de várias formas, através de compiladores e outras ferramentas (de AOP, por exemplo).

Praticamente qualquer parte do código gerado para rodar dentro do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) tem alguns metadados informando o que é aquilo. Muitas vezes isto é feito indiretamente através dos [atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101) ([alguns exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101)).

Estas informações são essencialmente descritivas e vão desde versões, assinaturas e informações poucos relevantes para o código em si, até informações cruciais para o funcionamento da CLR e o .NET como um todo. Em geral elas são marcações sobre como um tipo está definido, como um método deve ser usado, informações auxiliares para membros de um tipo, restrições para parâmetros, só para citar alguns exemplos. Elas podem ser usadas para configurar certos aspectos pelos compiladores das linguagens, pelo Visual Studio, outras ferramentas, o próprio CLR em vários dos seus componentes, incluindo [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) e GC e .NET e seus *sub-frameworks*, além das próprias aplicações dos usuários.

Estas informações podem ser acessadas através de [reflexão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Também pode usar uma ferramenta externa para consultar isto fora da execução, como o [`ildasm.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (já tem melhores).

Pense nestes dados como propriedades dos elementos do código, mas no fundo [o nome é atributo mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101). São adjetivos do que cada parte do código deve ser ou se comportar. É como criar um banco de dados com informações adicionais que estão relacionados ao código, mas não fazem parte dele diretamente.

Acredito que as perguntas *linkadas* mostra bem como deve ser feito o uso. Na [documentação oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/retrieving-information-stored-in-attributes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) tem exemplos de como usar a reflexão para ler estes dados. Tem como [escrever novos atributos personalizados](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E tem como [aplicar os atributos aos membros do código](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/applying-attributes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Um exemplo de uso seria criar um atributo de *label* para usar em propriedades de classes que servem como modelo para algum *framework* de apresentação. Então é possível gerar uma "tela" automaticamente com os membros desta classe imprimindo nome junto aos campos de acordo com esses atributos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).