# Qual é o nome destes parâmetros no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, atributos

Qual é o nome destes parâmetros entre colchetes utilizados para restringir algum acesso ou definir o protocolo utilizado, como no exemplo: `[Authorize]` e `[HttpPost]`.

É possível criar um "filtro" personalizado? para, por exemplo, permitir o acesso a usuários com um nível de `Role` específico.

[image: Código no Visual Studio]

Comment: Faz 3 perguntas que estou te falando sobre escrever estes filtros: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estas construções são [atributos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), não são parâmetros. Faz parte da sintaxe o C#. O atributo é apenas uma informação, chamada de [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101). Ele sozinho não faz nada. precisa existir um mecanismo no código que o leia e faça alguma coisa.

Os que está vendo não deixam de ser personalizados. Foi o ASP.NET MVC que os criou, neste caso eles são chamados de *action filters*.

Você pode criar os seus também, seguindo algumas regras. Obviamente precisa haver um motivo para criar um e ter algum mecanismo que os consuma.

- [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa criar um novo atributo para limitar a autorização por ROLE. Você pode usar o próprio Authorize, por exemplo:

```
[Authorize(Roles="User")]
```

Agora se você realmente gostaria de criar um novo atributo, segue algumas informações.

Você pode criar um atributo personalizado da seguinte forma:

```
public class Author : System.Attribute
{
   private string name;
   public double version;

   public Author(string name)
   {
       this.name = name;
       version = 1.0;
   }
}

[Author("P. Ackerman", version = 1.1)]
class SampleClass
{
    // P. Ackerman's code goes here...
}
```

Porem o atributo por si só não faz nada. Você precisa criar uma rotina que utilize de reflection para identificar os atributos e dar algum significado para eles. Abaixo cito um link de referência que explica melhor.

Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx