# Entendendo estruturas no arquivo AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, .net, atributos, .net-assembly

Dando uma olhada no arquivo `AssemblyInfo.cs` de um projeto C# me deparei com algumas estruturas dais quais não estou reconhecendo. Trata-se das linhas:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription ( "" )]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany ( "" )]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

Em outras linguagens que tenho experiência eu diria que são `dicionários`. Mas em C# `dicionários` não são assim.
Que tipo de estruturas são essa? Algum tipo de lista?

Comment: Os comentários gerados junto com o código diz que são atributos. Mas estamos falando do mesmo recurso de atributos (`decorators` em python, `annotations` em java)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato, eles são chamados de [atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101). São basicamente anotações que podem ser usadas em diversos contextos. No caso nesse cria-se [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) para informar e configurar como o *assembly* se comportará.

Não tem nada a ver com dicionários, a não ser que alguma linguagem use uma terminologia fora do padrão do que todo mundo usa.

Mais sobre os atributos pode ser lido em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101).

Você pode inclusive [criar um atributo personalizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119024/101).

No caso postado só o [`AssemblyCulture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) tem utilidade mais que informativa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas um atributo não tem sempre que estar acompanhando de um método ou classe já que eles visam modifica-los? Atributos sozinhos no código, sem estar "decorando" uma classe ou método são válidos?

Comment: Não, como eu disse, pode estar em diversos contextos. E atributos não modificam nada, são apenas informações que podem ser usadas para alguma coisa em algum lugar. Nem faria sentido ter limitação para usar em tão poucos lugares. Os detalhes sobre a utilização estão nos *links* que eu apontei.