# Como preencher dados do INPI num projeto .NET

Tags: c#, .net, atributos, .net-assembly

Minha pergunta é de certa forma conceitual.

Minha empresa registrou o software no INPI e recebeu os dados de protocolo, etc.

Como preencher esses dados no meu sistema?

Eu notei que no arquivo `AssemblyInfo.cs` eu tenho campos que me permitem este preenchimento. A dúvida é como preencher.

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CBIP.Business.UI.Web")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("CBIP.Business.UI.Web")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2015")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

Qual é a forma correta de preencher estas informações?

Comment: Qual é a dúvida, especificamente? Se os campos estão ali não é só colocar os valores?

Comment: Na verdade o INPI dá um conjunto de informações. Protocolo, Número de Pedido, Tipo de Programa, Campo de Aplicação. A única coisa que encontrei no protocolo que bate com esses campos é o nome da empresa. O resto eu estou perdido. Há, por exemplo, uma data de entrada do pedido de proteção, mas não há uma data de vigência, para colocar no Copyright, por exemplo.

Comment: Mas esses dados são puramente descritivos, é só fazer uma telinha de about e vida que segue.

Comment: Será dup? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156167/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe forma correta porque estes atributos são puramente descritivos e você pode por do jeito que quiser, um ou outro tem alguma semântica que se for seguida pode ser usada por alguma ferramenta específica.

Algumas pessoas vão colocar no `Copyright`, outra no `Trademark`, e ainda alguma [criarão um atributo próprio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119027/101) para colocar isto.

Mas sinto em te dizer que será uma informação *misleading* quase instantaneamente, porque apesar do arquivo *assembly* ser baseado em fontes que você registrou, ele logo não será mais. Assim que você começa mexer nos fontes depois do registro, ou você registra de novo ou aquilo já não é mais o objeto registrado.

Claro que tem alguma vantagem, mas eu já vi quem registrou ser roubado e não conseguir fazer nada porque o fonte roubado não era mais o registrado, com poucas alterações a pessoa escapa de ter feito algo errado do ponto de vista legal.

Comment: Muito informativo. Obrigado @Bigown.