# Como funcionam os atributos do PHP 8?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, php-8

No PHP 8, foi introduzido os [attributos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.syntax.php), que podem ser usados em classes ou métodos.

Exemplo:

```php
namespace MyExample;

use Attribute;

#[Attribute]
class MyAttribute
{
    const VALUE = 'value';

    private $value;

    public function __construct($value = null)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}

// b.php

namespace Another;

use MyExample\MyAttribute;

#[MyAttribute]
#[\MyExample\MyAttribute]
#[MyAttribute(1234)]
#[MyAttribute(value: 1234)]
#[MyAttribute(MyAttribute::VALUE)]
#[MyAttribute(array("key" => "value"))]
#[MyAttribute(100 + 200)]
class Thing
{
}

#[MyAttribute(1234), MyAttribute(5678)]
class AnotherThing
{
}
```

Eu tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito disso:

- Como faço para recuperar os valores desses atributos definidos na classe ou método?
- Qual é a finalidade dos atributos? Atributos tem como finalidade alterar o comportamento do método/classe, ou são apenas dados extras?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/484081/5878, duplicada?

Comment: @Woss concordo que parte da pergunta esteja duplicada, exceto referente à "como posso recuperar os valores definidos"?

Comment: Na outra é comentado que é via reflexão. Talvez possa solicitar ao autor da resposta para adicionar um exemplo lá para tornar a resposta mais completa (ou mesmo editar a resposta)

Comment: Concondo com ser duplicata, pedir por exemplos/esclarecimentos em comentário ou até colocar uma recompensa seria melhor que criar uma nova pergunta, pelo menos nesse caso

Comment: @Costamilam deixei em aberto para comunidade decidir. Se tiver um acréscimo na outra resposta, acho que vale a pena fechar essa mesmo.

Comment: Eu reabri a pergunta. Faltou detalhes de como deve ser implementado o `Attribute` nas respostas da outra pergunta. A outra responde apenas em parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Qual é a finalidade dos atributos? Atributos tem como finalidade alterar o comportamento do método/classe, ou são apenas dados extras?

De acordo com a documentação:

> Os atributos permitem adicionar informações de metadados estruturados e legíveis em declarações no código: classes, métodos, funções, parâmetros, propriedades e constantes de classe podem ser o destino de um atributo. Os metadados definidos pelos atributos podem ser inspecionados em tempo de execução usando as APIs do Reflection [...]

Sendo assim, os atributos não tem como finalidade de alterar o comportamento do método ou função, como no caso do Decorator do Python, mas sim, apenas adicionar metadados (informações extras).

> Como faço para recuperar os valores desses atributos definidos na classe ou método?

Como dito na documentação, você precisa utilizar a [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.reflection.php). A API Reflection permite você acessar informações de uma classe, função, método, parâmetros e etc.

Exemplo:

```php
#[Attribute]
class Route
{
    public function __construct(protected string $path) {}

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
}

class UsuariosController
{
    #[Route("/usuarios")]
    public function index()
    {
    }
}
```

Você poderia recuperar essa informações assim:

```php
$reflection_method = new ReflectionMethod(UsuariosController::class, 'index');

foreach ($reflection_method->getAttributes(Route::class) as $reflection_attribute) {

    $route = $reflection_attribute->newInstance();

    echo $route->getPath(), "\n"; // "/usuarios"
}
```

Observe que a classe que representa seu atributo personalizado precisa sempre conter a declaração `#[Attribute]` nas suas declarações.

Além disso, note que o método `Reflection::getAttributes` retorna um `array` de `ReflectionAttribute`. Isso porque você pode declarar mais de um atributo em uma classe ou método.

Veja:

```php
class UsuariosController
{
   #[Route("/usuarios")]
   #[Route("/usuarios/listar")]
   #[RouteName("usuarios.listar")
   public function index() 
   {
      //
   }
}
```

Nessa pergunta, tem uma resposta que explica melhor a natureza dos atributos:

- [O que são atributos no PHP? (Annotations/Attributes/Decorators)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484081/o-que-s%c3%a3o-atributos-no-php-annotations-attributes-decorators)