# O que define uma classe de atributo no PHP 8?

Tags: php, atributos, php-8

Estou usando atributos do PHP 8, a documentação desse recurso ainda é rudimentar, só contém exemplos de código e a api não está documentada então estou experimentando o uso do recurso.

```php
class MeuAtributo {}

#[MeuAtributo]
class Teste {}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass(Teste::class);
$attributes = $reflection->getAttributes();
var_dump($attributes[0]->newInstance());
```

Ao executar esse código o seguinte erro ocorre na chamada de `newInstance()`:

```
Attempting to use non-attribute class "MeuAtributo" as attribute in /code/index.php:10
```

- O que é a classe de atributo mencionada na mensagem?
- Como corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que são atributos no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484081) e [Como funcionam os atributos no PHP 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/487642/4995)

Comment: Geralmente, eu costumo fechar como **erro de digitação** perguntas que tenham algo parecido como "esqueci de colocar X" por desatenção ou ter deixado passar um detalhe despercebido  da documentação,  ou mesmo "erro de sintaxe". Aqui no stackoverflow é interessante que as perguntas estejam formuladas de maneira a ajudar não só a si próprio, mas também os demais usuários. Ao meu ver, faltou atenção na hora de implementar o Attribute.

Comment: Esqueci aquela hora de deixar o [link da documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.attributes.classes.php) para ajudar um pouco. Ainda está em inglês, somente.

Comment: Esse recurso de Reflection é novo no PHP ou sempre teve? Se for que nem o do Java, é desnecessário em 99% dos casos, nem aconselho a aprender muito, só a saber que existe. A maioria dos casos que achar que dá pra usar vai ser melhor fazer sem. E se for que nem o do Java ainda por cima é lerdo. _Just saying_

Comment: @Piovezan Reflection do PHP existe desde 2004 com a versão 5. Não tenho informações sobre performance. mas sei que alguns frameworks usam (em injeção de dependências). Especificamente para a parte de atributos/annotations reflexão é a única forma de acessar esse recurso ([em C# também](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/))

Comment: @PedroSanção Necessário ele é, senão não teria sido criado, mas em código de aplicações finais tende a ser mal utilizado. É o tipo de recurso para se ter em mente junto com herança múltipla, sobrecarga de operadores e coisas assim. Mas nesse caso dos atributos posso estar falando besteira porque não sei como é esse recurso de atributos no PHP, devem ser diferentes de campos como é o no conceitual, mas eu olhei por cima o código e interpretei como pegando campos do objeto (P.S.: Agora entendi, são tipo as annotations do Java mesmo. Bem, continuam sendo voltados mais p/ criar frameworks, não?).

Comment: @PedroSanção Cara, me desculpe, eu entrei na pergunta e comecei a falar tudo num nível hipotético e nem me toquei que você está usando atributos/reflection, achei que estivesse apenas tentando entender como funcionam. Não tive intenção de criticar esse uso em específico, que nem sei qual está sendo. Não entrei no mérito, só generalizei.

Comment: Tudo bem @Piovezan. Acho que annotation é o equivalente no Java sim

Comment: Bom, se for como no Java, a tendência é essa mesma que falei para reflection e annotations customizadas, saber que existem, ter noção de como funcionam, e deixar mais para os frameworks usarem: https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-annotations-in-java e https://stackoverflow.com/q/9222621/2241463 Em linguagens dinâmicas como no PHP reflection pode ter a vantagem extra de converter strings em campos de um objeto ou o oposto, e talvez também métodos, o que pode ser um pouco mais útil em alguns casos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TD; DR:

Para definir uma classe de atributo classe adicione `#[Attribute]` antes da classe:

```php
namespace App;

use Attribute;

#[Attribute]
class MeuAtributo {}
```

O `use` é necessário somente quando a classe usa `namespace`, como nesse exemplo.

---

### Entendendo classe de atributos

A definição de classes de atributos está descrita [nessa página do manual (sem tradução)](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.attributes.classes.php). Ainda assim acho útil fazer um paralelo com linguagens que já utilizam esse recurso, como C# por exemplo, pois falta descrição conceitual do recurso.

Os atributos fornecem um método eficiente de associação de metadados, ou informações declarativas, ao código (classes, métodos e propriedades, funções, constantes de classe, parâmetros). Após um atributo ser associado a uma entidade de programa, o atributo poderá ser consultado no tempo de execução usando uma técnica chamada reflexão.

Os atributos têm as seguintes propriedades:

- Os atributos adicionam metadados ao seu programa. Os metadados são informações sobre os tipos definidos em um programa. Você pode adicionar atributos personalizados para especificar qualquer informação adicional necessária.
- Você pode aplicar um ou mais atributos a classes, métodos e propriedades, etc.
- Os atributos podem aceitar argumentos.
- Seu programa pode examinar seus próprios metadados ou os metadados em outros programas usando reflexão.

Uma classe de atributo é uma classe que deriva direta ou indiretamente da classe `Attribute`, o que faz com que a identificação das definições de atributo nos metadados seja rápida e fácil. Suponha que você queira marcar tipos com o nome do programador que escreveu o tipo. Você pode definir uma classe de atributos `Author` personalizada.

### Na prática

`Attribute` tem um parâmetro opcional para limitar onde essa classe de atributo pode ser utilizada, esse argumento aceita uma combinação das constantes usando `|` (operador de bit "OU"):

```
Attribute::TARGET_ALL;
Attribute::TARGET_CLASS;
Attribute::TARGET_CLASS_CONSTANT;
Attribute::TARGET_FUNCTION;
Attribute::TARGET_METHOD;
Attribute::TARGET_PARAMETER;
Attribute::TARGET_PROPERTY;
```

Por exemplo:

```
#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_METHOD | Attribute::TARGET_FUNCTION)]
class Exemplo {}
```

Permitirá que a classe de atributo `Exemplo` seja utilizada apenas como atributos de métodos e funções.

### Sobre os erros

O erro destacado na verdade é uma exceção e pode ser capturada com `try/catch`. Ocorre quando há algum problema com a implementação, seja falta do atributo (o erro apontado na pergunta) ou uma restrição de uso (descrita acima).

Comment: Acho que faltou o `use Attribute;`, **se não me engano**, precisa dele

Comment: @Costamilam só precisaria do `use` se o arquivo usasse `namespace`, como nesse exemplo não foi usado ele não é necessário

Comment: Se quiser, pode adicionar isso a resposta, pra ficar mais completo